# Unable to connect bluetooth mouse and android phone

Tags: android, bluetooth

How to connect a bluetooth mouse and android phone using bluetooth . i want to connect my phone to a bluetooth device which can be a mouse . if i get the mouse scan and get it and paired it but  how to connect those device.

Comment: You want to implement something, or what? Have you tried at least something?

Comment: I am not geeting any solutution to connect a mouse with device ....i have connect two android device

Comment: Have you tried at least something? --> I am not geeting any solutution --> not trying to find a solution for yourself or even write properly ? Enjoy downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth mouse is just a name. They are not using any bluetooth related services or anything. Mouse and its receiver works on particular **Frequency** so you can't connect to that frequency using **Bluetooth**.

As per example you can't connect someone else mouse with your receiver. So frequency matters. :)

Hope you understand. Good Luck

Comment: But in practical i have coneected the my android device with my bluetooth mouse..

Comment: Your question has title "Unable to connect..." and you just written "i have coneected". Still don't know what is your problem. When you are paired you are connected.